# A launchd job without plist file, how does that work and how to find what job triggers it?

Tags: launchd

I am having a hard time to figure out how those unwanted program autostarted in the system. I am running MacOS Big Sur.

Take an example, Please have a look at the following job:

```
$ launchctl list | grep -i thunder
405 0   com.xunlei.Thunder.ThunderHelper
```

```
$ launchctl print gui/$(id -u)/com.xunlei.Thunder.ThunderHelper
com.xunlei.Thunder.ThunderHelper = {
    active count = 4
    copy count = 0
    one shot = 0
    path = (submitted by otherbsd.330)
    state = running

    program identifier = com.xunlei.Thunder.ThunderHelper
    parent bundle identifier = com.xunlei.Thunder
    parent bundle version = 4368
    inherited environment = {
        SSH_AUTH_SOCK => /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.ZGX7Lm6JIp/Listeners
    }

    default environment = {
        PATH => /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
    }

    environment = {
        XPC_SERVICE_NAME => com.xunlei.Thunder.ThunderHelper
    }

    domain = com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100006.Aqua
    asid = 100006
    minimum runtime = 10
    exit timeout = 5
    runs = 1
    successive crashes = 0
    pid = 405
    immediate reason = semaphore
    forks = 0
    execs = 1
    initialized = 1
    trampolined = 1
    started suspended = 0
    proxy started suspended = 0
    last exit code = (never exited)

    semaphores = {
        successful exit => 0
    }

    event triggers = {
    }

    endpoints = {
        "com.xunlei.Thunder.ThunderHelper" = {
            port = 0x9a333
            active = 0
            managed = 1
            reset = 0
            hide = 0
        }
    }

    dynamic endpoints = {
        "com.xunlei.Thunder.MessageHelper" = {
            port = 0xac607
            active = 1
            managed = 0
            reset = 0
            hide = 0
        }
    }

    pid-local endpoints = {
        "com.apple.tsm.portname" = {
            port = 0xbecaf
            active = 1
            managed = 0
            reset = 0
            hide = 0
        }
        "com.apple.axserver" = {
            port = 0xbe833
            active = 1
            managed = 0
            reset = 0
            hide = 0
        }
    }

    instance-specific endpoints = {
    }

    event channels = {
    }

    sockets = {
    }

    instances = {
    }

    spawn type = interactive (4)
    jetsam priority = 3
    jetsam memory limit (active) = (unlimited)
    jetsam memory limit (inactive) = (unlimited)
    jetsamproperties category = daemon
    submitted job. ignore execute allowed
    jetsam thread limit = 32
    cpumon = default
    job state = running

    properties = {
        partial import = 0
        xpc bundle = 0
        keepalive = 0
        runatload = 0
        low priority i/o = 0
        low priority background i/o = 0
        dataless file mode = 0
        legacy timer behavior = 0
        exception handler = 0
        supports transactions = 1
        supports pressured exit = 0
        supports idle hysteresis = 0
        enter kdp before kill = 0
        wait for debugger = 0
        app = 0
        system app = 0
        creates session = 0
        inetd-compatible = 0
        inetd listener = 0
        abandon process group = 0
        event monitor = 0
        penalty box = 0
        role account = 0
        launch only once = 0
        system support = 0
        inferred program = 0
        joins gui session = 0
        joins host session = 0
        parameterized sandbox = 0
        resolve program = 1
        abandon coalition = 0
        high bits aslr = 0
        reslide shared cache = 0
        disable resliding = 0
        extension = 0
        nano allocator = 0
        no initgroups = 0
        start on fs mount = 0
        needs implicit endpoint = 0
        is copy = 0
        disallow all lookups = 0
        system service = 0
        protected by submitter = 0
        multiple instances = 0
    }
}
```

I am wondering how this job started automatically? How does it really work?

What does `submitted by otherbsd.330` path mean here?

I don't find a plist file anywhere which is responsible for this job.

Thanks a lot.

---

Btw, I am not sure the following words related to this question or not. You can ignore the following words. I just want to provide more information which may help on this issue.

I asked another question regarding how to delete hidden login iterms from `$HOME/Library/Application Support/com.apple.backgroundtaskmanagementagent/backgrounditems.btm`. So far, there is no answer yet. Inside `backgrounditems.btm`, it has this `ThunderHelper` process too. Since I don't find a proper way to delete the login iterm. It's hidden and not shown in system preferences. I delete the file compeletely with command `rm backgrounditems.btm`, but magically, after I shutdown and restart the system, this login iterm will automatically be created again inside a new `backgrounditems.btm` file.

I am thinking to change this file's owner and group permission. Make root as the owner and other  user only readable permission. I haven't tried this approach. Hopefully, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

launchd jobs can be submitted directly (through launchctl, and likely through cocoa code) without using a plist file. Since I see this line:

```
parent bundle identifier = com.xunlei.Thunder
```

that suggests the application with that bundle identifier (probably 'Xunlei Thunder', a peer-to-peer networking thing) is setting up a helper app (ThunderHelper) to run independently in the background.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reply. But how can I find who triggers this from the start? I want to prevent this happen, in order to achieve it, I need to know how it works. I am a programmer and new to MacOS (an experienced Linux user). First, I don't run `thunder` app by myself. Second, I have `rm backgrounditems.btm` which is the one contains thuner login iterm. Third, I have killed thunder process by PID. But, magically, after I shutdown and start MacOS again. The thunder login iterm will be added to a new backgrounditems.btm file. This launchd job will be auto started. How come? Thanks.

Comment: You can try `launchctl remove com.xunlei.Thunder.ThunderHelper` and see if that kills it. Submitted jobs are kept alive by default, meaning that launchd will restart it if it stops in an irregular fashion. But the next time you run Thunder it will reload the helper app.

Comment: I have tried `launchctl remove`. I have killed the PID too. Right now, I just want to figure out how it auto starts after system boots. Since I am a programmer, I am very careful when I do test cases. I guarantee that I don't start the app by myself. It's **OK** that those jobs and login iterms will be created when I start the app. That is NOT magic. What I don't understand is how it magically starts iteself after system boots when I never start the app after I `stop`, `remove`, `kill`, `rm backgrounditems.btm` etc.. Sorry about my limited Enlgish skill. I am not sure if you get what I mean.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and I have upvoted your answer. Becase figuring out how it auto starts might be a different question, I have created another question at: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/418465/ . Just FYI.

Comment: The `remove` command didn't prevent the helper from restarting? Hm. well, the other thing to consider is that *any* app which is launched (by any means) will show up as a launchd job; launchd is the main process hierarchy in the system. Check `~/Library/Startup Items` and `/Library/Startup Items`, or search your drive for 'ThunderHelper' or any aliases to it and see it it's in any special folders.

Comment: @sgon00: Ah... I just discovered that the situation might be more annoying than expected. See [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW5-BAJJBJEG)... Apparently an app can contain a helper app and automatically load it as a service at login. it can only be stopped if the app tells it to stop (through a preference or menu item). Check Thunder to see if this is the case; you might have to delete Thunder entirely.

Comment: Thanks a lot for keep searching my problem. I found a even worse case. After killing/remove any running thunder processes (inlcuding `rm backgrounditems.btm`). I moved Thunder.app to other directory: `mv /Applications/Thunder.app/ $HOME/tmp/thunder_tmp/`. And then restart macos system. The most weird thing happened. Thunder helper app started automatically from the new path and login iterms added to new backgrounditems.btm file. It seems MacOS searches my entire harddrive to find all helper app and starts them automatically and added them to login iterm. If this is true, it's very scary!

Comment: @sgon00: yeah, nice the helper app has it's own bundle id the system will always find it, if the directory is mounted at login. You could try moving Thunder to a removable drive, that you don't connect until you need it; that will keep it out of the system's view...

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. Why does the system always try to find the bundle id? Does it register somewhere so the system will always try to find the registered bundle id? OR does the system always scan the entire drive to find any helper apps? I think I will simply remove the Thunder.app directory. Whenever I need to use this app, I will simply mount the downloaded dmg and use the dmg file directly. But before removing it, I would like to understand the concept and logic behind this autostart. I don't want the system to scan my entiure disk at every boot. Cheers.

Comment: @sgon00: Whenever an app is launched. the system registers it (using the bundle id). I don't know the details, though I suppose I could look on Apple's developer pages, but the idea is that if the user requests an app (by trying to open a file, running a script, or etc), the system can find the app wherever it is on disk. In this case the app itself is registering the helper as a login item, so at login the system generates an automatic request for the helper at login, which locates and launches it.

Comment: @sgon00. if the helper is unreachable at login, the request will fail, and life will go on without it. I don't know if the system is smart enough to cancel the login request at that point, or if it will keep asking; you might have to do trial and error on that. You should read that documentation link I provided more thoroughly if you want those answers; that's the best reference I know for how the system handles daemons.

Comment: Thank you very much for the updated info. I will do more search then.

Answer (score 0):

[“KnockKnock”](https://objective-see.com/products/knockknock.html) is a free application that will help you locate all sorts of “auto-launch” processes.

Look for the "Launch Items" for `launchd` processes:

[image: Launch Items]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I am having it in my system too. The thunder app is not in the Launch Items in KnockKnock and it does not help me figure out how thunder helper app auto starts itself too. It does shows thunder app in Login Iterms though. But I can not really remove it. You can find more details in my another two related questions https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/418423/ and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/418465/ .  Thank you very much.